# Can't display video coming in from NetStream properly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I am basically starting work with Flex and netstream for video calls. So I was able to read a bit about Netstreams and streaming and I wrote this code to get my camera and publish my stream in a video display below in the view but even though I pass through all the methods without any error, the display is not showing so I don't really know what's going on. Here is what I did.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" applicationDPI="160" creationComplete="start();">
    <fx:Script>
        import flash.media.Camera;
        import flash.media.Video;
        import flash.net.NetConnection;
        import flash.net.ObjectEncoding;
        import flash.events.AsyncErrorEvent; 
        import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
        import flash.net.NetStream;
        import mx.graphics.ImageSnapshot;
        import mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder;

        public var camera:Camera;
        var video:Video;
        public var myVideo:Video;
        private var nc:NetConnection;
        private var rtmpf:String="rtmfp://p2p.rtmfp.net/61c33c80be7022350a0dea3d-960194f988ba/";
        private const DEVKEY:String = "61c33c80be7022350a0dea3d-960194f988ba";

        public var in_ns:NetStream;
        public var out_ns:NetStream;
        public function start():void{
            trace("Started the start function");
            nc=new NetConnection();
            nc.objectEncoding = ObjectEncoding.AMF0;
            nc.client=this;
            nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
            nc.connect(rtmpf);
        }
        public function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void{
            switch(event.info.code){
                case "NetConnection.Connect.Success":
                    trace("Received the status");
                    initStart();
                    default:
                    trace( event.info.code);
            }
        }

        public function initStart():void{
            trace("Started the initstart function");
            initNetStream();
            initMyVideo();
            publish();
            playIt();

        }

        public function initNetStream():void{
            trace("Started the initNetstream start function");
            out_ns=new NetStream(nc);
            out_ns.client=this;
            in_ns=new NetStream(nc);
            in_ns.client=this;
        }

        public function publish():void{
            trace("Started the publish function");
            camera=Camera.getCamera();
            out_ns.attachCamera(camera);
            out_ns.publish("Me", "live");

        }
        public function startCamera(muteCam:Boolean=false):void{
            if(!video)
            video = new Video(); 
            trace("Started the startCamera function");
            camera=Camera.getCamera();
            if(muteCam){
                video.attachCamera(camera);
                //out_ns.attachCamera(camera);
                //out_ns.publish("Me", "live");
                vidHolder.addChild(video);
            }else{
                video.attachCamera(null);
                if(contains(video))
                    vidHolder.removeChild(video);
                //camera=null;

            }


        }
        public function initMyVideo():void
        {
            trace("Started the initmyvideo function");
            myVideo = new Video(230,160);
            myVideo.x = 10;
            myVideo.width = 230; 
            myVideo.height = 160;
            myVideo.y = 30;
        //  myVid.addChild(myVideo);
        }

        public function playIt():void{
            trace("Started the play it function");
            myVideo.attachNetStream(in_ns);
            in_ns.play("Me");
            myVid.addChild(myVideo);
        }

        public function stopCamera():void{
            vidHolder.removeChild(video);
        }
    </fx:Script>
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->

    </fx:Declarations>

    <s:Button x="116" y="28" label="Start" click="startCamera(true)"/>
    <s:VideoDisplay id="vidHolder" x="31" y="87" width="200" height="100"
                    />
    <s:VideoDisplay id="myVid" x="31" y="250"/>
    <s:Button id="stop" x="208" y="28" label="Stop" click="startCamera(false)"/>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: I ran your code as is, and it seemed to work. I saw the video coming from my webcam. Can you clarify what part of this is not working?

Comment: Oh, it looks like you're trying to use two NetStreams with the same NetConnection? So maybe you're trying to figure out how to show the other person's video? If so, I'd recommend using a second NetConnection for the other NetStream (I've always done it that way, maybe it works your way). Following your code is a bit confusing, so I'll stop guessing at what is happening/going wrong and let you clarify.

Comment: Finally, I suggest you add a NetStatusEvent handler on the NetStreams too. You will get status messages that indicate that publishing has started, etc. These will help you trouble shoot what is occurring, just be sure to trace out all of the values of `event.info.code`.

Comment: @SunilD. Thanks a lot for trying it out. What I was basically trying to do was send a video stream of myself and then receive it back and I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

These are some reasons that is stopping from displaying the stream.

> Are you testing it on the same browser using your same webcam device
>   driver ?

Possibility is that you were not able to see it maybe since the driver is being used.
 Get a virtual webcam driver from a website [ManyCam](http://www.manycam.com) and test it out. Your application will work.